# Filter the List of JSON Objects by comparing the criteria with RETROFIT in android

Tags: android, retrofit

Here is my code to display list of student list

```
private void requestData(String uri) {

    RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint(ENDPOINT)
        .build();

    StudentsAPI api = adapter.create(StudentsAPI.class);

    api.getFeed(new Callback<List<Student>>() {

        @Override
        public void success(List<Student> arg0, Response arg1) {
            studentList = arg0;
            updateDisplay();
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
      });
```

//interface

```
public interface StudentsAPI {

@GET("/data/students.json")
public void getFeed(Callback<List<Student>> response);

}
```

i want to filter the list by comparing course. How can i compare the strings and display the result.

Answer (score 0):

I am hoping you must be using a View(ListView,RecyclerView,GridView ) to display your data hence, the comparing logic can be written inside the List/Recycler/Gridview View Adapter's getView() or onBindViewHolder() methods based on the element in your studentList List and the position something like

```
 @Override
public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.student_row, null);

    CustomViewHolder viewHolder = new CustomViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder customViewHolder, int i) {
    Student student = studentList.get(i);

    if(student.getCourse()==filter){
                customViewHolder.textView.setText(student.getName());

    }
    else{
         customViewHolder.getView().setVisibility(View.Gone);
    }


}
```